# how to upload image folder to colab?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I was trying to upload a big image folder into google drive and github but github not allowed and google drive taking too long. How can I upload the local folder to colab.

Comment: Google Drive sync is likely the best option. How large is the folder, and what's the transfer rate?

Comment: about 345MB, taking too long.

Comment: you are saying it takes too long because of slow internet?

Comment: internet speed is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I don't think there's a solution to your issue. If your fundamental problem is limited upload capacity from the machine with the images, you'll just need to wait.

A nice property to uploading to Drive is that you can use programs like [Backup and Sync](https://www.google.com/drive/download/backup-and-sync/) to retry the transfer until it's successful. And, once the images have been uploaded to Drive once, you'll be able to access them quickly in Colab thereafter without uploading again. (See [this example notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=u22w3BFiOveA) showing how to connect your Google Drive files to Colab as a filesystem.)

Answer (score 0):

convert the folder to zip file and then upload it on colab.
further you can unzip your folder by following command.
! unzip "your path"

Answer (score 0):

The unzip method only works for csv files.
If you use a kaggle dataset, use

```
os.environ['KAGGLE_USERNAME'] = 'enter_username_here' # username
os.environ['KAGGLE_KEY'] = 'enter_key_here' # key

!kaggle datasets download -d dataset_api_command_here
```

If you have the image in google drive, use

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```